# Echoed data as a input value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, input, echo

I can't figure out how to get MySQL data echoed as a input value. It is for item edit purpose. I need to get data inside of input tag. Here is my code that doesn't work. It work just with textarea tag.

```
$ID = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fm where ID = $ID";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    

    $title = $row['title'];}}
```

... etc.

```
<input type="text" name="title" vlaue="<? echo $title;?>">
```

Comment: Typo? `vlaue` should be `value`.

Comment: May not be the main issue, but by `vlaue` you probably meant `value`

Comment: Guys, you would not believe but you are right.. thank you so much - took me two days of trying to solve it.

Comment: loll i upped this one because happened to me before also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="title" vlaue="<? echo $title;?>">
```

change it to

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<? echo $title;?>">
```

Also, make sure the query runs, the correct id is passed as GET parameter, it has a corresponding record in the database, the corresponding record has a title value and it is correctly returned.